# Group queries inside a cfloop

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfquery, cfloop

I'm looking to loop through a query, and would like to use grouping, like one would using `cfoutput`. I know CF10 added that support, but is there a script that emulates that behaviour so that items can be iterated easily?

---

**Edit:**
There are ways of getting around the lack of grouping in `cfloop`, by rearranging `cfoutput` tags, so they are not nested. The reason I'm looking for the `cfloop` workaround is that when nesting `cfoutput`, you need to use the results from the same query. I'd like to use my own QoQ and loop through the result.

Comment: If you want to loop through a query as one can with `<cfoutput>`, why do you not just use `<cfoutput>`?

Comment: If there is already an `<cfoutput>` used, you cannot insert another one inside. And if it wasn't required, they probably would not have included it in the latest ColdFusion

Comment: No need to get snippy. I'm trying to understand your issue. Had you said that from the outset, I'd not need to ask, would I? I never suggested the CF10 functionality wasn't a godsend (I was one of the chief proponents of getting it into the language, as it happens). What I asked was why you couldn't just use `<cfoutput>` which you - in no way - explained in your question. You should still update your question to include this info, as it's kinda critical to it.

Comment: One can generally work around an outer `<cfoutput>` block by shifting the boundaries of it not surround the code block you need to group/loop in. Doing that would probably be less hairy code than doing the grouping "by hand". I can explain how to do that though, if you'd prefer (the better option would be to sort out the nesting of your output tags if poss, though).

Comment: You can have nested `<cfoutput>` tags if you specify the `group` attribute. [See documentation for ColdFusion 8 here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_m-o_16.html)  which sounds like what you are after anyway.  Right?  I agree with @AdamCameron that your question probably needs more info.

Comment: sorry Adam, wasn't trying to be snippy.. I'll update the question with more detail

Comment: Oh, and I just checked... are you sure that "cannot nest `<cfoutput>` tags" thing still applies in CF8? I know it used to be a problem ages ago, but I just chucked some code together and it's not *intrinsically* a problem...?

Comment: You can't nest this `<cfoutout><cfoutput query="A">` at least not in CF9

Comment: @Busches: well *I* can (just did). However I *cannot* nest two query output-loops, which is what Daniel needs as it turns out.

Comment: @AdamCameron your CF9 is different than mine. This: `<cfoutput><cfoutput query="test"></cfoutput></cfoutput>` threw this `Invalid tag nesting configuration.`, as expected.

Comment: OK, lemme recheck @ revert in a minute.

Comment: @Busches Doh! I stand corrected, sorry to disagree with you before. Dunno what I was running before (I *did* knock out some test code before making the comment, but obviously hadn't saved the last change before running it or something).

Comment: @Daniel - How many levels? A *single* level of grouping is relatively simple ie `if (query.currentRow eq 1 or valueInCurrentRow neq valueInPreviousRow) { output the value; }` If you need more than that, it gets complicated ..

Comment: can you post some sample code? we might be able to help you come up with a better way without going through a ton of trouble

Comment: The question's not clear - what does the query/queries you want to group look like, and what columns are desired to group on? What aspects of your view code are fixed? (i.e. what's stopping you refactoring as in Adam's answer?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so you want to do this sort of thing:

```
<cfoutput query="query1">
    <!--- stuff --->
    <cfoutput query="query2" group="col>
        <!--- more stuff --->
        <cfoutput>
            <!--- still more stuff --->
        </cfoutput>
        <!--- almost the last stuff --->
    </cfoutput>
    <!--- last stuff --->
</cfoutput>
```

?

And the second loop gives you an error:

```
Invalid tag nesting configuration.

A query driven cfoutput tag is nested inside a cfoutput tag that also has a query attribute. This is not allowed. Nesting these tags implies that you want to use grouped processing. However, only the top-level tag can specify the query that drives the processing.
```

You should be able to revise that to:

```
<cfloop query="query1">
    <cfoutput>
        <!--- stuff --->
    </cfoutput>
    <cfoutput query="query2" group="col>
        <!--- more stuff --->
        <cfoutput>
            <!--- still more stuff --->
        </cfoutput>
        <!--- almost the last stuff --->
    </cfoutput>
    <cfoutput>
        <!--- last stuff --->
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

There's another option to emulate the group loop if you must. But that's a bunch of thinking and typing I'd rather avoid if poss, so let me know if this approach works first.

Comment: "that's a bunch of thinking and typing I'd rather avoid" agreed, I just thought someone would have done this already as the requirement for this functionality doesn't seem that unreasonable. The option you showed is how I would deal with it if I wanted to refactor the code.

Comment: I'm sure someone will have some code they'll pop up any minute. I'm Surprised Peter Boughton hasn't shown up yet (you *did* chant "Candyman Candyman Candyman Candyman Candyman", right? ;-)